# Splitting strings with regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, split, expression

Can someone please tell me why the result that I get is different from the book?

Here is the code

```
<?php
$address = "username@example.com";
$arr = split ("\.|@", $address);
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr))
{
    echo "<br/>".$value;
}
?>
```

Here is the result the book says you should get

```
username
@
example
.
com
```

Here is what I got when I try the code on my computer

```
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\Apache24\htdocs\test3.php on line 3

username
example
com
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` function has been deprecated since PHP 5.3.0.

Use `preg_split()` instead.

The usage of this is the same as `split()`.

Comment: Oh so the book is outdated. Thank you so much kRiZ. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, the usage is still the same so you can use this new function exactly like `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

The book is wrong in that you should not get the delimiter characters themselves, only the 'words' between them.

The warning is due to `split()` about to being discontinued in favor of `preg_split()`, so you should replace it with

```
$arr = preg_split ('/\.|@/', $address);
```

to prevent the warning.

I'd recommend that you split by `@` only first, and only then split the domain name by `.`, otherwise you wouldn't know whether `foo.bar@example.com` or `foo@bar.example.com` lead to a

```
foo
bar
example
com
```

result.

Comment: Thank you Hartmut I'll read more about preg_split on php.net website. I really appreciate your answer.